# Go to currently selected option on submit button press?

Tags: html

```
<form>
  <label for="department" >Department</label>
  <select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" id="department" name="department">
    <option value="departments/scso.html">SCSO</option>
    <option value="departments/fsp.html">FSP</option>
    <option value="departments/dhs.html">DHS</option>
    <option value="departments/fng.html">FNG</option>
    <option value="departments/dot.html">DOT</option>
    <option value="departments/doc.html">DOC</option>
    <option value="departments/dpw.html">DPW</option>
    <option value="departments/scfd.html">SCFD</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This currently goes to the option's value as soon as you click it, but I want to put that submit button to use so I replaced the onchange with this:

```
<script>
  var goBtn = document.getElementById("submit");
  var menu = document.getElementById("department");

  goBtn.onclick = function() {
    window.location = menu.value;
  }
</script>
```

But instead of the nice "/department/__.html" ending like the onchange has, it gives me a weird "/?department=departments%2F__.html" ending when you press the submit button, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
  var goBtn = document.getElementById("submit");
  var menu = document.getElementById("department");

  goBtn.onclick = function() {
    window.location = menu.options[menu.selectedIndex].value;;
  }
</script>
```

The reason for the value you are getting is that the value gets serialized into a name=value format.. in your case: department=departments/scso.html.. the `/` is then URL escaped resulting in the `%2F`

Comment: I'm still getting the same weird ending